# Why hasn't Music.SE's name changed on data.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, site-name

Recently (~ November 6th), the name of *Musical Practice and Performance* was changed to **Music: Practice & Theory**.*

But, on data.stackexchange has not changed yet:
[image]
[image]

Will it be changed?

*[*Music SE is getting a new name — Music: Practice & Theory*](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/989/music-se-is-getting-a-new-name-music-practice-theory?cb=1)

Comment: When did the actual name change go into effect? If it was after November 23rd, then the Data Explorer hasn't been updated with new data yet. Otherwise the Stack Exchange team might have to poke it with their pointy sticks.

Comment: I *think* it has to be updated manually anyway, @animuson (making the answer to the question in the title "because no one's changed it").

Comment: WordPress and Travel also have old site names there. Oh, and "Statistical Analysis"... Also, the meta sites of English and Electrical Engineering still bear the old names of those sites on Data.SE (the names were changed long ago).

Comment: @animuson it changed somewhere around nov. 6th

Comment: Because you have not made a request to the forum owner? Does the documentation of the topic name need to equate with the ideation of the topic name? Sorry to get too meta here.

Comment: Ahh, well, you should see if you can change it back for practice! :) Cheers.