# CogSci is now Psychology.SE but SEDE isn't aware of it

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

SEDE seems to be unaware of the name change on Cognitive Sciences (to [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/)).

The site icon is a broken image and the text of the site name still reads "Cognitive Sciences" instead of "Psychology & Neuroscience".

> [image: SEDE image from list of all sites]

This image is from the list of all sites and is representative of both the main site and meta site list items. The "visit site" link URL is also still "cogsci.se.com" but that is valid because it's a redirect, though the "correct" link "psychology.se.com" would probably be preferred.

Comment: This has been an issue for a while [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244356/why-hasnt-music-ses-name-changed-on-data-stackexchange), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261517/sede-should-pick-up-on-changes-to-community-metadata) and the discussion about how to solve are discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293127/data-dump-programmers-and-software-engineering). I'm going to close as a dup of that as we need to figure out how to solve it for all of them.

Comment: @Taryn It's not a duplicate of that. That one asks about the data *dump*; this one asks about SEDE. If anything, this is a dupe of this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306338/a-site-url-changed-and-now-its-icon-in-sede-is-broken?rq=1

Comment: @Ano The discussion covers SEDE.

Comment: @Taryn Actually, Software Engineering does not have the same problem, as its [name and icon in the **UI**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aobS5.png) are up-to-date (the question you closed this as a duplicate of is about the name of the SEDE database, which is different than the UI). This question should be instead closed as a duplicate of [mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306338/323179) & the duplicate votes on my Q for the Programmers question should be removed.

Comment: @Laurel this post discusses both the icon and the name in SEDE and since there is already a discussion about it I closed it as a dup of the Software Engineering post because it encompasses a similar problem - when a site changes names there are issues that need to be resolved.

Comment: @Taryn would you take a gist with a sql statement to update the `BadgeIconUrl` in the `sites` table to fix this? I also hope that what is in the dupe gets done but that will take 6 to 8 years and I don't fancy looking at broken windows for that long. I'll write the gist to fix all occurrences (writers -> writing is another one) if you're happy to run it on the StackExchange.Data db

Comment: What is the SEDE site? What is their specialised topic??

Comment: SEDE is "the Stack Exchange Data Explorer" - it's a tool for looking through the sites, not a site on its own.

Comment: let me link my answer here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332277/158100