# Some sites names shown in Data Explorer Stack Exchange doesn't match the current site name. Is this a bug or a feature?

Tags: bug, meta, data-explorer, site-name, required-tags

#### Volume 1 : TL;DR

Please fix the names of the sites in Data Explorer of Community Building, Music: Practice & Theory, Medical Sciences, Mythology and Folklore, Bricks, Cross Validated and "Beer, Wine & Spirits".

##### Second attempt to explain why this question is not a duplicate of the current duplicate target

This is not a duplicate of [Why hasn't Music.SE's name changed on data.stackexchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244356/1359324) b/c that post is not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request); it's a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) that is closed as duplicate of [Data dump, Programmers and Software Engineering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293127/1359324), another [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

More about why it is not a duplicate:

- [Why hasn't Music.SE's name changed on data.stackexchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244356/1359324) has no answers and has 6 comments. Only one comment is from the Staff team, more specifically from [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson), but it was a request for clarification. There were no more comments, links in the question body, or comments pointing to a definite answer.
- [Data dump, Programmers and Software Engineering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293127/1359324). This question is about data dumps, not Data Explorer Stack Exchange; it has three answers 1 from Adam Lear, Staff, and 1 from Shog9, a former Staff.

  - [Adam's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293145/1359324) created in 2017 mentions possibible actions. There is no progress update.
  - [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293202/1359324) created in 2017 mentions a possible solution. There is no progress update.
  - [Jason's C answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293142/1359324) created in 2017 is interesting. It includes a link to a Google Sheet spreadsheet with data retrieved in 2017. It has a comment from Jason from 2021 about support for tables.

##### Conclusion

As non of the questions in the duplicate chain is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and they don't mention that the current state of Data Explorer Stack Exchange is [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design), this question should not be closed as a duplicate of any of them.

---

#### Volume 2: A Stack Exchange tale

A lengthy but possibly necessary writing that provides context for this post and it's evolution into a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

##### Preface

I was not able to find the duplicate target before posting this question. The answer to a composed question that was originally included in the Epilogue,

> **What should be done when it's noticed that a site name in Data Explorer Stack Exchange doesn't match the site name? Should it be done here or in the corresponding per-site-meta?**

... posts a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), as explained below:

The target duplicate is obsolete, as it was created in 2014; on the other hand, it is closed as a duplicate of a new post created in 2017. The three answers are from 2017; non of them look to be definite answers and don't answer what is being asked here.

[Taryn's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364168/1359324) to [A site URL changed and now its icon in SEDE is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306338/1359324) ([bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)) mentions that several sites were fixed. The sites mentioned here are not included, and currently, the Data Explorer Stack Exchange requires a fix to show the current site names of several sites.

Considering this, I have replaced [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

##### Chapter one

While using a SEDE query to get the site activity of Community Building, I noticed that the autocomplete options include Moderators, the old site name, instead of the current name. This is because the site was changed several years ago.

After posting [As of May 8th, 2023, Community Building still appears as Moderators in Data Explorer Stack Exchange](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1416/7020) in Community Building Meta, I noticed more sites in the same situation, graduated and beta.

| Site name shown on SEDE homepage | Current Name | Related |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Moderators | Community Building | [link](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1416/7020) Created in 2023. Open. |
| Musical Practice and Performance | Music: Practice & Theory | [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244356/1359324) Created in 2014. Closed as duplicate. |
| Health | Medical Sciences |  |
| Mythology | Mythology and Folklore |  |
| LEGO® Answers | Bricks |  |
| Statistical Analysis | Cross Validated |  |
| Beer | Beer, Wine & Spirits | [link](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/q/232) Created in 2019. Bug caused by ampersand in site name |

Several sites that have changed their name, like Software Engineering, are shown using the current name instead of the old one.

While I tagged the Community Building Meta post as a [feauture-request](/questions/tagged/feauture-request), I'm not sure what meta-tag should be used here as the site names are manually updated. So I'm wondering if, as it's done with the list of sites that have changed their name is maintained by the community, the track of the names of the sites shown in Data Explorer Stack Exchange should also be tracked by the community. Also, I wonder if the site-name process has a community-created guide / [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

##### Epilogue

What should be done when it's noticed that a site name in Data Explorer Stack Exchange doesn't match the site name? Should it be done here or in the corresponding per-site-meta?

As explained in the preface, the answer is to post a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), so I turned this [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) into a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). Please fix the site names for the sites mentioned above.

##### Related

- [Data dump, Programmers and Software Engineering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293127/1359324)
- [Was Programmers (now Software Engineering) the first SE site to change its name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286108/1359324)
- [Why hasn't Music.SE's name changed on data.stackexchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244356/1359324)

##### Addendum

From the referred Community Building Meta post

> Data Explorer Stack Exchange
> Community Building
> [image: Data Explorer Stack Exchange - Community Building]
>
> Site Activity and VoteGraph by rolfl
> Top
> [image: Site Activity and VoteGraph by rolfl - Top]
> Bottom
> [image: Site Activity and VoteGraph by rolfl - Top]
>
> Autocomplete options
>
> Co
> [image: Autocomplete options - Co]
>
> Comm
> [image: Autocomplete options - Comm]
>
> Mod
> [image: Autocomplete options - Mod]

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of the first question you mention under 'Related', as it also asks how to deal with that discrepancy. Dupes are based solely on questions, not on their answers, and that no answer there satisfies your needs is unfortunately not a reason to keep this one open.

Comment: @Joachim Actually, it's the other way; Dupes are based on answers. A question might be closed as duplicate of a question that asks something completely different if it has an answer that answers the question being reviewed.

Comment: @Joachim Turned this [tag:discussion] into a [tag:bug]. The edit includes the explanation for this change.

Comment: Related: [The single source of truth for the site list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359796)

Comment: Related : [Why doesn't the homepage of SE sites explain what the site is for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289216/1359324)